# ReferenceError when trying to run Puppeteer in Typescript

Tags: typescript, puppeteer, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to use Puppeteer in a SvelteKit project with Typescript. I'm using [this boilerplate](https://github.com/ollefrost/ollesvelke).

I did:

```
npm install --save-dev puppeteer @types/puppeteer
```

I created a `.ts` file and put:

```
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
```

Then I imported that `.ts` file in one of my `.svelte` files.

When I deployed my app to `localhost` to render said `.svelte` file in my browser, this error is displayed:

```
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at node_modules/pump/index.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/puppeteer.js?v=bf147010:16220:33)
    at __require2 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-UC7LELEO.js?v=bf147010:48:44)
    at node_modules/get-stream/index.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/puppeteer.js?v=bf147010:16346:16)
    at __require2 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-UC7LELEO.js?v=bf147010:48:44)
    at node_modules/extract-zip/index.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/puppeteer.js?v=bf147010:17730:21)
    at __require2 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-UC7LELEO.js?v=bf147010:48:44)
    at node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserFetcher.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/puppeteer.js?v=bf147010:26161:41)
    at __require2 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-UC7LELEO.js?v=bf147010:48:44)
    at node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Puppeteer.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/puppeteer.js?v=bf147010:27326:31)
    at __require2 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-UC7LELEO.js?v=bf147010:48:44)
```

How do I solve?

None of these have worked:

- Installing `@types/node`.
- [Modifying my `tsconfig.js`.](https://www.lewuathe.com/using-puppeteer-in-typescript.html)

Comment: Hey, having your `package.json` would be helpful to be able to reproduce the problem. Of course, a "skeleton" project on GitHub would be even better.

Comment: @ironstone13 here's the sveltekit boilerplate I start off with -https://github.com/ollefrost/ollesvelke; added it to the question

Comment: Thanks! So, how does your build process look like? I assume `svelte-kit build`  does not build `.ts` out of the box, so you need a plugin , or compile directly using `tsc`?

Comment: it uses [`vite-plugin-svelte`](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte), which the [default sveltekit template](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs) also uses

Comment: I'm not sure that puppeteer should ever be imported (directly or indirectly) into a .svelte file. I would expect you to have a separate test runner process that kicks off and launches a headless browser to run tests _against_ your Svelte app—not to be used as part of the app itself.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a [SSR](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/appendix#ssr) error. The code in your `.svelte` files is run first in the server, and it seems puppeteer can't spin up a virtual browser instance on the server.

The easiest way to fix this is to check if you're running in the browser. You do this by importing the `browser` variable from `$app/env`:

```js
import { browser } from "$app/env";

if (browser) {
    import('puppeteer').then(puppeteer => {
        // Do your stuff
    })
}
```

If you want to export the module (or anything else), you can export an empty variable and assign it a value later.

```js
import { browser } from "$app/env";

export let puppeteer;

if (browser) {
    import('puppeteer').then(module => {
        puppeteer = module
    };
}
```

You can also consider disabling SSR and making essentially a SPA. However, it is [heavily discouraged in the SvelteKit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/appendix#ssr), so I would advise against it.

Comment: Also, you have to remove `target: '#svelte'` from your `svelte.config.js` file in your template (I had to remove it myself to get your demo working!).